# Implicit interface procedure pointer member for derived type

Tags: fortran, function-pointers, intel-fortran

In a derived type, I am trying to use a generic procedure function pointer member-type in order to point to different same derived type-bound procedures, which happen to have different interfaces.

```fortran
module SharedMod

use SettingsMod
implicit none

type, public :: shared_t
   type(settings_t)      :: settings
   ...
contains
   ...
   procedure, pass   :: run
   procedure, nopass :: readSettings, getSettingsFromProg
end type shared_t

contains

subroutine run(this, sett_file)
   class(shared_t) :: this
   character(len = 132), intent(in), optional :: sett_file

   if (present(sett_file)) then
      this%settings%GetSettings => this%readSettings
   else
      this%settings%GetSettings => this%getSettingsFromFinelg
   endif
#if defined __PROG__
   call this%settings%GetSettings(this%settings)
#else
   call this%settings%GetSettings(this%settings, sett_file)
#endif
   ...
end subroutine run

...

subroutine readSettings(setts, file)
   class(settings_t) :: setts
   character(len = *), intent(in) :: file
   integer   :: itmp
   real(RDP) :: rtmp


   print *, '@Shared::readSetting() : reading settings from file..'
end subroutine readSettings

subroutine getSettingsFromProg(setts)
   implicit none
   class(settings_t) :: setts
   
   print *, '@Shared::getSettingsFromProg() : reading settings from PROG..'
end subroutine getSettingsFromProg

end module
```

```fortran
module SettingsMod

implicit none

type, public :: settings_t
   ...
   procedure(), public, pointer, nopass :: GetSettings => null()
end module
```

When compiling using `ifort` I get:

```fortran
error #8191: The procedure target must be a procedure or a procedure pointer.   [READSETTINGS]
this%settings%GetSettings => this%readSettings

error #8191: The procedure target must be a procedure or a procedure pointer.   [GETSETTINGSFROMFINELG]
this%settings%GetSettings => this%getSettingsFromFinelg
```

I also tried the version where `GetSettings()` is a type-boud procedure, i.e.

```fortran
module SettingsMod
...
type, public :: settings_t
   ...
contains
   procedure(), public, pass :: GetSettings => getSettingsFromProg, readSettings
   ...
end type settings_t

abstract interface
   subroutine getSettingsFromProg(this)
      import settings_t
      class(settings_t) :: this
   end subroutine getSettingsFromFinelg
end interface

abstract interface
   subroutine readSettings(this, file)
      import settings_t
      class(settings_t) :: this
      character(len = *), intent(in) :: file
   end subroutine readSettings
end interface
...
end module
```

having :

```fortran
error #6784: The number of actual arguments cannot be greater than the number of dummy arguments.   [GETSETTINGS]
call this%settings%GetSettings(sett_file)
```

At this point, I have two questions:

1. Why do I get these errors??
2. How would you suggest to implement such a concept, if I was clear enough to explain it?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT** after first @Vladimir 's comment.

After having post the answer in which I show how I finally found a working solution, still, I have more questions now:

1. Why did it work adding `()` just to the type-bound procedures pointed to?
2. Why did it work **without pointer assignment**?
3. Why did the equivalent type-bound procedure version not worked, even providing `abstract interface`s to the two external procedures?

Still look forward to discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for the **function-pointer** procedure member-type version, after having added `()` after the `procedure` keyword in the `shared_t` type-bound procedures:

```fortran
module SharedMod

use SettingsMod
implicit none

type, public :: shared_t
   type(settings_t)      :: settings
   ...
contains
   ...
   procedure, pass   :: run
   procedure(), nopass :: readSettings, getSettingsFromProg
end type shared_t

contains

subroutine run(this, sett_file)
   class(shared_t) :: this
   character(len = 132), intent(in), optional :: sett_file

#if defined __PROG__
   call this%settings%GetSettings(this%settings)
#else
   call this%settings%GetSettings(this%settings, sett_file)
#endif
   ...
end subroutine run

...

subroutine readSettings(setts, file)
   class(settings_t) :: setts
   character(len = *), intent(in) :: file
   integer   :: itmp
   real(RDP) :: rtmp


   print *, '@Shared::readSetting() : reading settings from file..'
end subroutine readSettings

subroutine getSettingsFromProg(setts)
   implicit none
   class(settings_t) :: setts
   
   print *, '@Shared::getSettingsFromProg() : reading settings from PROG..'
end subroutine getSettingsFromProg

end module
```

```
module SettingsMod

implicit none

type, public :: settings_t
   ...
   procedure(), public, pointer, nopass :: GetSettings => null()
end module
```

Still, I have more questions now:

1. Why did it work adding `()` just to the type-bound procedures pointed to?
2. Why did it work **without pointer assignment**?
3. Why did the equivalent type-bound procedure version not worked, even providing `abstract interface`s to the two external procedures?

Looking forward to discussion.

Comment: Code you move or copy your current subuquestions into your question? This site works in quite a specific way.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава is it ok like this?

Comment: Yes. You could also may have kept a copy of them in the answer, that is up to you. It just important that thr reader of the question knows what you are finally interested in.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I understand. Still, the questions are still opened, so if you have some nice suggestions, I'd be more than happy to learn from them :)